# Extending Layout .xml files not working in child theme in different <vendor> as to parent theme: Magento 2.0.4

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

### Steps to reproduce

1. Installed Magento 2.0.4 on WAMP server 3.0 , Windows 10 Pro - 32bit, PHP 5.6.15, MySQL 5.7.9
2. Created a child theme **themeparent**  of **Magento_blank** in app\design\frontend\**Vendor1**\themeparent with several layout xml files for extending, along with template .phtml files. Activated from admin. Working Fine.

theme.xml => `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`

3. Created another child theme **themechild**  of above theme *themeparent* (which is itself the child of magento blank). This childtheme is created in different vendor folder, i.e. *Vendor2*
   This theme path is app\design\frontend\**Vendor2**\themechild . Created layout .xml file inside to extend its parent theme layout. Activated this second level child theme from admin. The .xml files not even processed. Not working.

theme.xml => `<parent>Vendor1/themeparent</parent>`

3b. Although template .phtml files or .css files existing in *childtheme* are working fine if corresponding layout containers/blocks called in from the **Vendor1**\themeparent layout files.

4. If for a test, the same child theme *childtheme* put inside same vendor of its parent i.e. **Vendor1** , the theme path becomes app\design\frontend\**Vendor1**\themechild and then the same layout .xml files works fine.

Already tried with clearing *public/static* and *var* folders of magento. Also, tried after running with cli commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But nothing solved it.

### Expected result

The required theme inheritance is in this way:

Magento_blank => *Vendor1*_themeparent => *Vendor2*_childtheme . (note vendor differ)

Result: Layout .xml fail to load in childtheme.

But if for a test, inheritance made this way:

Magento_blank => *Vendor1*_themeparent => *Vendor1*_childtheme . (note vendor same)

Result: Layout .xml load properly and work fine in childtheme.

As per Magento 2 guidelines on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#set-a-parent-theme it is clearly mentioned that **"A parent and a child theme can belong to *different vendors*. For example, your custom theme can inherit from the Magento Blank theme."** . So, if I am creating a second level child theme (in vendor 2) from a parent theme (in vendor 1) which is a child of Magento_blank (vendor: Magento), this should ideally work fine. But its not happening. None of the layout .xml files processed to output if they are under  different vendors. If I put both themes in same vendor, they are working fine.

### Actual result

Extending layout .xml files in the 2nd level child theme in different vendor folder is not working.

**Why Magento 2.0.4 not working properly for 2 level theme inheritance with different vendor names?**
This is a serious issue, as if you suppose purchased a paid theme from somewhere (which they have created by inheriting Magento_blank), and now you want to create your child theme of that paid theme but in different vendorname folder (obviously under your companyname), you will not able to do so!
You have only two choices left, either make your child theme inside their vendor name; or edit their theme .xml files to call your child theme template files or .css/.js (if in ur vendorname); the second case will obviously loose updates, weird way and not recommended.

Then what is the solution??

Answer (score 5):

Giving it more time to find the reason, I created different set of parent and child theme with different vendornames, and checked it on same installation and it worked!
I was amazed, matched the way to what I have done earlier in my themes; old and new both exactly same. Again activated my childtheme, and surprisingly it not worked. More surprised and fedup. :(

Then I digged into the **magento database**, and I found out one amazing thing. In the '**theme**' **mysql table** of magento database, somehow the '**type**' column corresponding to my childtheme had value set as '1' and all others were set '0'. Under suspicion, I tried to find what it means by comment in table column name which shows..

```
0 => Physical
1 => Virtual
2 => Staging
```

I guessed it may be a reason, and manually set the 'type' column value to **0** corresponding to my childtheme. Cleared var and public/static folders. Re-tested, and voila! it worked!!

This small issue has wasted my 4-5 days, with no solution. Even deactivation-activation or switching themes from admin was not resetting its value to 0 (it always remained 1) and so it never worked.

For a cross check to confirm, I deleted that row from database theme table, and reinstalled the theme, ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, and now its setting the value to 0, which is perfect and working automatically.

Don't know how it was set to 1 and when. It should be 0.

Anyways, the issue is solved now, and

> I found a very tiny thing but a VERY BIG thing

, which can waste every developers time if not known. 
But, **surprisingly this silly point is no where mentioned on the internet and not even on the magento documentation, which must be there**.
Hope this explanation and solution will help more people later who are getting frustrated with the same issue. :)

This issue is also raised and explained on https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330

Thanks.

Comment: I think this scenario happens if those situations where we deploy a theme and then remove it temporarily, in that case it sets the type as 1. When the theme is added back the type is not updated.